How to reduce the height of curly braces around aligned environment with [t] parameter
I want to reduce the height of the surrounding curly braces of an aligned environment which uses the [t] parameter.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    This is some inline text. 
    $
    \left\{
    \mbox{This is some more: }
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        a&=b\\
        b&=a
    \end{aligned}
    \right\}
    $
    .
\end{document}



You can exploit nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

This is some inline text.
\hphantom{\Bigg\lbrace}%
$\begin{NiceArray}[t]{@{}l@{\ }l@{}}
  \mbox{This is some more: } &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        a&=b\\
        b&=a
    \end{aligned}
\CodeAfter\SubMatrix\{{1-1}{1-2}\}
\end{NiceArray}
$
    .
\end{document}


I'm not seeing any application of this, however.
